# Unknown Number of Conditions in 'which' Statement

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I have a **selectInput** that allows users to select multiple countries. I want to get that countries and create a data from it.

Like that:

```
data_multicountry<-data[which(data$Country==input$countryInput[1] |
                              data$Country==input$countryInput[2] |
                              data$Country==input$countryInput[3]),]
```

But conditions can be more or less. For example;

```
data_multicountry<-data[which(data$Country==input$countryInput[1] |
                              data$Country==input$countryInput[2] |
                              data$Country==input$countryInput[3] |
                              data$Country==input$countryInput[4] ),]
```

I can get the lenght of selected countries list.
How can I add OR statements programmatically?

Comment: Use `%in%`. See `?match` For instance `data$country %in% input$countryInput[1:3]`. Also, `R` indexing is 1-based, so `input$countryInput[0]` is not probably what you want.

Comment: Edited indexing. Do you mean   `data_multicountry <- data[which(data$Country %in% input$inputCountry[1: length(input$inputCountry)]),]`. It doesn't work.

Comment: As a suggestion, you should *never* say `it doesn't work` without explaining what's not working. Do you receive an error? An unexpected result? Green goblins appeared on the screen? Please, describe better the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table` it's actually a pretty simple thing to do. First of all, you don't need to specify the name of the data set in the condition. `data.table` already knows that you are working with *this* table, so only the name of variable is required. Second, you may just create another variable or list that will store all the countries which your users have selected and then use that variable as a condition for your select. Please, refer to the example below.

```
> DT = data.table(var1=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), var2=c(1,2,3,4))
> DT
   var1 var2
1:    a    1
2:    b    2
3:    c    3
4:    d    4
> lst=list('a','d')
> DT[var1 %in% lst,]
   var1 var2
1:    a    1
2:    d    4
```

[Here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) is a great FAQ on `data.table`.

Comment: Pointing to the new [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) might be more helpful.